# Magento 2: Custom price-options

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.5

I want to change price-options on custom options price to per character.

**example:**
Custom Options price set to **$20** and max character is 10. If total character is 5, Custom Options price will be calculate ($20 * 5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solutions for my question.
I'm using jquery keyup(), and use basePrice for price calculation.

```
this.options.optionConfig[optId].prices.basePrice.amount
```

Comment: could you please specify file name for your changes. I hope i have same requirement.  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/287934/magento-2-apply-custom-pricing